# How to troubleshoot 'Root Element is missing' when using EPPlus on complex spreadsheet

Tags: epplus

using version 4.5.3.2 of EPPlus on a spreadsheet produced in Excel. Using a test:

[image: Unit test produces XmlException]

I am getting an XmlException "Root element is missing". I can load the file in Excel (MS Office 365 ProPlus) without any problems. How do I a diagnose? Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm it is an XLSX and not an XLS?  Epplus only supports XLSX.  If you rename to .zip and open in something like 7-zip, do you see the XML files inside?

Comment: Yes, I was able to open the file as zip and confirm its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the issue, but debugging this test resulted in abnormal behavior; running the test resulted in the test executing correctly and I am able to make assertions about the UUT just fine. I just can't inspect parts of the test as it executes.

Comment: That is very strange.  Are you maybe running any threads or somehow require running under `STA`?  Good to hear you at least have it working.